# How to create a Salesforce app like Mailchimp

Tags: salesforce, crm, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I am looking to create a Salesforce app like mailChimp (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3byfEAB) have. I want to create an interface under the salesforce to allow the user to do some field mapping, Just like Mailchimp app allow to map the Mainchimp field and Salesforce Contact fields. I have gone thought the Salesforce documentation but found it very vast not getting where to start and did not found which kind of scripting it require to create the app.

I have a developer and a partner account. If any one can put some light on it and give me some short answer for the below question will be really helpful.

1. Where to start for creating an slesforce app.
2. The app we create from the Salesform CRM account and app listing on AppExchange is different?
3. Is this apps are hosted on salesforce itself or hosted in our own server?
4. Which scripting language is required to code the Salesforce app?
5. Can we call the external API's inside the Salesforce app?

Answer (score 0):

After asking question, I also work on this to get the answers for my question. I am sharing my RND below, So it may help someone and can save their time.

Here is the [complete document link](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/9/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf) for the app creation and publishing on app Exchange, you can go thought it and find all the answers step by step.

So below are the very short answers of the question I asked.

- Where to start for creating an slesforce app.

Step 1: Sign Up for the Partner Program

Step 2: Create a Development and Test Environment

Step 3: Get a Business Org

After doing the above 3 steps you can get a environment hub into Business Org, By which we can create different organization to create the app in one org (that is dev org) and install and test into the other org( that is test org).

- The app we create from the Salesform CRM account and app listing on AppExchange is different?

Yes, From Your CRM account you can create the app, package the app in beta version. Once you done the testing with beta app by installing it into your Test Org you can deploy it for app exchange, After security review you app will be available into app exchange publicly. You can do it from your salesforce CRM account itself (See the above doc for more details)

- Is this apps are hosted on salesforce itself or hosted in our own server?

There are two types of app:

1.VisualForce Pages app: This app is besically a collection of VisualForce Pages and reside or hosted into the saleforce itself.

2.Connected App: Connected app also includes the VisualForce pages as need but it also provide the client id and client secret key by which we can authenticate the user and call the Salesforce REST API from the outside of the CRM. So we can say this is something we can host the API access code into our own server.

- Which scripting language is required to code the Salesforce app?

For Coding into the VisualForce pages we required Salesforce Apex Scripting and HTML.

- Can we call the external API's inside the Salesforce app?

Yes, Using the Apex HTTP class we can call the external API's into the salesForce.

Hope this will help someone.